# KineticJS : scaling issue while using custom clipFunc on 2x pixel aspect display

Tags: kineticjs, retina-display, clipping

Kineticjs automatically adopts canvas size and whole graphics on Retina displays, so all looks sharp and clean without blurry pixelation. But thing goes wrong when I try to use custom clipping function.

Here is some code

```
this.layerOne = new Kinetic.Layer();
this.layerTwo = new Kinetic.Layer({
 clipFunc : function(c){
 var ctx = c.getContext();
  ctx.rect(0,0,width,height);
 }
});
```

If I add shape on layerOne it will be rendered perfectly considering 2x pixel aspect, but the same shape added on layerTwo will be rendered ignoring pixel aspect, thus not beign scaled up by 2. As a result shapes on layer with clipFunc becomes 2x smaller.

**How can I resolve this problem?**

P.S. Here is some quick [example I've made on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7HwS/4/)

- Light Green is background, Dark Green is 100 pixel square, both on non cropped layer;
- Light Yellow is 100 pixel square, and pink is rectangle with width equals to stage, they are on cropped layer;

On normal screen we see Yellow's width is equal Light Green's width, and properly cropped. Pink is not visible because is being out of clipping region.

On Retina display we see Yellow is smaller than Dark Green and Pink is particularly visible. Dark Green and Pink shows us that cropping rectange has normalized dimentions for Retina, but all graphics scaled down.

Standart
[image: Non-Retina]

Pixel Aspect = 2
[image: Retina]

**UPDATE**: Same in Chrome on my Galaxy Nexus
**UPDATE**: Everything looks perfect in Safari on OS X! Other major browsers (FF, O, Chrome) on OS X are affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this bug I've modified `kinetic-v4.5.5.js` source as mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077427/kineticjs-scaling-issue-while-using-custom-clipfunc-on-2x-pixel-aspect-display#comment26020645_17091875)

Answer (score 1):

looks like a bug, I'll add this to my todo list.  The fix will be to scale the path according to the pixel ratio, before rendering it.  i.e. if the pixel ratio is 2, then we need to scale the path by a factor of 2.

Comment: yes, looks like a bug! I've just tested [this page](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-clipping-functions-with-kineticjs/), there is huge difference in behaviour while dragging object on standart and double pixel aspect screen: on HiRes display clipping rectangle moves too!
So, to fix I should apply to all shapes on layer with clipping  something like .setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, 0, 0)?

Comment: @Geradlus_RU Not sure if you already fixed it, since it's more than a month ago. Look for the last line in the `_clip` function and change it to `context.setTransform(this.pixelRatio, 0, 0, this.pixelRatio, 0, 0);` works for me for now...

Comment: @MarkSmits, I've just tried this hack and it does not worked in my case. Fortunately, this is not 'hot issue' for now, so I'm not hurrying to resolve this, but any way I need the solution or hack. Thank you!

Comment: If you are using the `.min.js`-file of KineticJS you have to replace it with `b.setTransform(this.pixelRatio, 0, 0, this.pixelRatio, 0, 0);`. By the way: @MarkSmits you are my hero! :D

Comment: @MarkSmits, oh I've didn't catch. Tried to modify my own code instead of source code. I'll try it it few hours.

Comment: @irie11, yes, but I'll switch to non minified version because of better readability.

Comment: for development the non compressed version is of course a better choice, but to reduce loading times for the end-users I would recommend to use the `.min.js` file after your coding is finished :)

Comment: Bravo!  That is indeed the correct fix.  This was just added to Kinetic v4.6.1 which will be released around mid September.