# KineticJS simple animation not working on mobile devices

Tags: ipad, animation, mobile, canvas, kineticjs

I was wondering if someone could help me find the solution to this. 
I've made a very simple animation using KineticJS. 
All works perfect on desktop, unfortunately not on mobile devices (iPhone, iPad, Android).

Result is a slowish performance but most importantly distorted shapes.

I suspect it has something to do with resolution or viewport but am not sure.

Preview is on www.bartvanhelsdingen.com

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Below is the code:

```
var shapes = {
    sizes: [30, 40, 50, 55, 60, 80],
    gradients: [
        [0, '#fdfaee', 1, '#524f43'],
        [0, '#a39175', 1, '#dbae5e'],
        [0, '#b4c188', 1, '#f3de7c'],
        [0, '#eaf2ef', 1, '#587c71'],
        [0, '#a39175', 1, '#dbae5e'],
        [0, '#61845c', 1, '#b4b092']
    ],
},
dims = {
    width: 300,
    height: 500
},
stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'animation',
    width: dims.width,
    height: dims.height,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    draggable: false
});

function getRandomColor() {
    return colors[getRandomFromInterval(0, colors.length - 1)];
}

function getRandomGradient() {
    return gradients[getRandomFromInterval(0, gradients.length - 1)];
}

function getRandomFromInterval(from, to) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}

function getRandomSpeed() {
    var speed = getRandomFromInterval(1, 1);
    return getRandomFromInterval(0, 1) ? speed : speed * -1;
}

function createGroup(x, y, size, strokeWidth) {
    return new Kinetic.Group({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        width: size,
        height: size,
        opacity: 0,
        draggable: false,
        clipFunc: function (canvas) {
            var context = canvas.getContext();
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(0, 0);
            context.lineTo(0, size);
            context.lineTo(size, size);
            context.lineTo(size, 0);
            context.rect(strokeWidth, strokeWidth, size - strokeWidth * 2, size - strokeWidth * 2);
        }

    });
}

function createShape(size, gradient, strokeWidth, cornerRadius) {
    return new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: size,
        height: size,
        fillLinearGradientStartPoint: [size, 0],
        fillLinearGradientEndPoint: [size, size],
        fillLinearGradientColorStops: gradient,
        opacity: 1,
        lineJoin: 'bevel',
        strokeWidth: 0,
        cornerRadius: cornerRadius
    });
}
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer(),
    animAttribs = [];

for (var n = 0; n < 6; n++) {
    var size = shapes.sizes[n],
        strokeWidth = Math.ceil(size * 0.12),
        cornerRadius = Math.ceil(size * 0.04),
        gradient = shapes.gradients[n],
        x = getRandomFromInterval(size, dims.width) - size,
        y = getRandomFromInterval(size, dims.height) - size;

    var group = createGroup(x, y, size, strokeWidth);

    var shape = createShape(size, gradient, strokeWidth, cornerRadius);

    animAttribs.push({
        nextChange: getRandomFromInterval(1, 3) * 1000,
        startTime: 1000,
        duration: 0,
        x: getRandomSpeed(),
        y: getRandomSpeed()
    });

    group.add(shape);
    layer.add(group);
}

stage.add(layer);

anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function (frame) {
    var time = frame.time,
        timeDiff = frame.timeDiff,
        frameRate = frame.frameRate;
    for (var n = 0; n < layer.getChildren().length; n++) {
        var shape = layer.getChildren()[n],
            opacity = shape.getOpacity() + 0.01 > 1 ? 1 : shape.getOpacity() + 0.01,
            attribs = animAttribs[n],
            x, y;

        if (attribs.duration >= attribs.nextChange) {
            attribs.x = getRandomSpeed();
            attribs.y = getRandomSpeed();
            attribs.nextChange = getRandomFromInterval(3, 5) * 1000;
            attribs.duration = 0;
        }

        if (time >= attribs.startTime) {
            if (shape.getX() + attribs.x + shape.getWidth() >= stage.getWidth() || shape.getX() + attribs.x - shape.getWidth() / 2 <= 0) {
                attribs.x *= -1;
            }
            if (shape.getY() + attribs.y + shape.getHeight() >= stage.getHeight() || shape.getY() + attribs.y - shape.getHeight() / 2 <= 0) {
                attribs.y *= -1;
            }
            x = shape.getX() + attribs.x;
            y = shape.getY() + attribs.y;
            attribs.duration += timeDiff;
            shape.setOpacity(opacity);
            shape.setX(x);
            shape.setY(y);
        }

    }
}, layer);
anim.start();
```

Comment: Nice animations. Just as a note, I tried looking at your website on my S3 and I didn't see **any** of the rectangles pop up at all. It was as if the stage did not load, or was completely outside of the screen. Hope that helps, I'll let you know if I come up with anything else.

Comment: Aha, thanx projeqht for the observation. I wish I could track/debug the mobile devices more but for now am lacking tools. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

the problem you are facing is, that `clipFunc` isn't currently working on devices with `pixelratio != 1`.

This problem came up in [this post](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki/Release-Schedule) as well. Eric Rowell, the creator of KineticJS added this issue to his [release scedule](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki/Release-Schedule#461-late-september) for late September.

So there is nothing wrong with your animations, they're working as expected, but you can't see them because of the distorted clipping region

To resolve this issue "unofficially" you can simply replace the last line of the `_clip` function in your kinetic.js with the following: `context.setTransform(this.pixelRatio, 0, 0, this.pixelRatio, 0, 0);` (credits for that go to [Mark Smits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17091875/1277120))

Comment: Great, thanx for the explanation. The animation is visible now. Only trouble is that some shapes leave a trace. Would anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: To my previous comment. On my samsung galaxy the trace issue is present only in it's built-in Internet browser, works well in firefox.

Comment: firefox on android is another kind of mobile browser I guess, because in my case clipping worked there even before I added the pixelRatio to the _clip function. Could you try it with another webkit-browser like chrome or safari to see if the traces are visible there?

Edit: I've just tried it on my iPad (safari) and Nexus 4 (chrome) and there everything seemed to work flawlessly ;)