# Scaling and touch interaction on Retina screens

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs, retina-display

I have a problem similar to one described in the following questions.
[KineticJS : scaling issue while using custom clipFunc on 2x pixel aspect display](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17077427/853872)

In my [application](http://aplus1games.com/iseam): (please try on retina ipad vs normal ipad or desktop browser, even iOS simulator would also do)

There is are two canvas layers, one of them contains a blanket group that I scale with pinch-zoom gesture in the range of 0.5x to 1.5x

On the retina screen my canvas gets zoomed out to 1/4 the screen when at 0.5x
Now, with the change suggested in the comments, I managed to make it scale it properly however touch events are no longer scaled accordingly. Any ideas whats going on here?

Note that it is working perfectly on non-retina screens.

Am using KineticJS 4.4.3 - as its was an academic project that began early this year for proof-of-concept and now I'm continuing it to make a complete application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem got solved after I upgraded to KineticJS 4.7.4

It however broke the clipping code I had as `clipFunc` was deprecated but that's a different issue which was resolved by resetting `clip` parameters on `dragmove` event.

Not an efficient solution but it works for now!